# How wordpress theme/plugins license works? and what power include it?

Tags: licensing

if i buy a theme/plugins from any company (not themeforest) and if they have a activation license for it, how it actually works? and what kind of power they will have? after active the theme with the license they have power to get accsess my website? or if they want they can stop my website? or anything else?

Or license is needed only to get theme/plugins support and they dont have any power or access to my website?

Kindly let me know, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It would be *highly* atypical for a license to stipulate such power as demanding access to your site, I mean who would trust it?

That said there are plenty of malicious code out there, especially if you are getting themes/plugins from shady distribution channels and/or pirated copies.

Also if extension supports updates then it does give vendor access to your site of sorts — in serving those updates to be installed on your site.

In a nutshell you should stick with reputable sources for your purchases. If you have high security requirements/concerns you should consider getting whatever code you use to be professionally audited for security issues.